# How to have my zero be printed at the end of a decimal number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am adding a .10 (dime) to my variable Value, but when I print the updated variable it only prints out 0.1, instead of 0.10. I need to keep the zero at the end.

```
Value= 0.00#before this was just 0
quarter = 0.25
nickel = 0.05
dime = 0.10
if s == "quarter":
    Value= Value + quarter
    print("Value: ", "$", float(Value))
elif s == "nickel":
    Value = Value + nickel
    print("Value: ", "$", float(Value))
elif s == "dime":
    Value= Value + dime
    print("Value: ", "$", float(Value))
```

I am not sure why the zero goes away when the value dime gets added to value :/

Comment: [Formatting Numbers for Printing in Python](https://blog.tecladocode.com/python-formatting-numbers-for-printing/)

Comment: Just beware of [using floating point types for money](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/10077).

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatting to achieve this,

See the example below. I used f-string to make the print statements look neat.

```
Value= 0.00#before this was just 0
quarter = 0.25
nickel = 0.05
dime = 0.10

s = "dime"

if s == "quarter":
    Value= Value + quarter
    print(f"Value : ${Value:.2f}")
elif s == "nickel":
    Value = Value + nickel
    print(f"Value : ${Value:.2f}")
elif s == "dime":
    Value= Value + dime
    print(f"Value : ${Value:.2f}")

# Output": Value : $0.10
```

If you don't want to use f-strings, alternatively you can use format to format the floating points for you,

```
Value= 0.00#before this was just 0
quarter = 0.25
nickel = 0.05
dime = 0.10

s = "dime"

if s == "quarter":
    Value= Value + quarter
    print("Value : $ {:.2f}".format(Value))
elif s == "nickel":
    Value = Value + nickel
    print("Value : $ {:.2f}".format(Value))
elif s == "dime":
    Value= Value + dime
    print("Value : $ {:.2f}".format(Value))
```